# Merge Sort in Python - IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Tags: python, sorting

I'm trying to implement merge sort in Python, but I keep getting the same mistake:
IndexError: list assignment index out of range. I based my code on the Java code by Sedgewick and Wayne found here: https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/22mergesort/Merge.java.html

Am I doing something wrong with the auxiliar array while trying to pass the items from vetorNum to vetorAux? What is it then?

```
vetorAux = [] * len(vetorNum)
nTrocas = 0
mergeSort(vetorNum, vetorAux, 0, len(vetorNum)-1)


def mergeSort(vetorNum, vetorAux, i, f):
    if(f > i):
        m = (i+f)//2
        mergeSort(vetorNum, vetorAux, i, m)
        mergeSort(vetorNum, vetorAux, m+1, f)
        intercala(vetorNum, vetorAux, i, m, f)


def intercala(vetorNum, vetorAux, i, m, f):
    global nTrocas

    if(i == f):
        return

    k = i
    while(k <= f):
        vetorAux[k] = vetorNum[k]
        k += 1

    i_aux = i
    m_aux = m+1
    k = i
    while(k <= f):
        if(i_aux > m):
            vetorNum[k] = vetorAux[m_aux]
            m_aux += 1
        elif(m_aux > f):
            vetorNum[k] = vetorAux[i_aux]
            i_aux += 1
        elif(vetorAux[i_aux] > vetorAux[m_aux]):
            vetorNum[k] = vetorAux[m_aux]
            m_aux += 1
            nTrocas += 1
        else:
            vetorNum[k] = vetorAux[i_aux]
            i_aux += 1
        k += 1
```

Comment: You can find great examples of codes (including merge sort) in python on Rosetta Code. https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Merge_sort#Python

Comment: You need to change your line `vetorAux = [] * len(vetorNum)` to `vetorAux = [0] * len(vetorNum)` instead. Otherwise `vetorAux` will be empty.

Comment: Worked now, thanks lcastillov. Also thanks Ulysse for the useful link.